# Gitlab Pipeline Only Merge Request

Tags: gitlab

Estou criando uma script para CI no *GitLab*, porém ao usar o `only merge_requests` o mesmo não é executado quando crio um novo *merge request*.

A versão que estou usando é a *Community Edition*.

Quando eu crio um novo *branch*, uma nova *tag* ou faço um *commit*, o *GitLab* dispara a *pipeline*, só não está disparando quando crio um novo *merge request*

Pode ser algo relacionado por eu estar usando a versão *CE*?

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: 'echo build'
  only:
  - branches
  - tags
  - merge_requests

test:
  stage: test
  script: 'echo test'
  only:
  - merge_requests

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: 'echo deploy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma limitação baseada na versão das ferramentas, você chegou a conferir isso?

Segue os pré-requisitos:
In GitLab 11.10 and later, you must be using GitLab Runner 11.9.

Essa informação esta [neste](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/) link.